# Python MapReduce length longest word and show longest word(s)

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to use MapReduce principles with Python to first Map segregated list of word from text with their number of characters, then reduce to display the longest words and its number of characters.

[See visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdKYM.gif)
Input is a simple text.txt file with 3 sentences.
See below my Mapper:

```py
#MAPPER
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        print(str(len(word)) + '\t' + word)
```

Thanks for helping for the Reducer. Required outcome is "The longest words in this text are xxxxxxxxx and yyyyyyyy with xx characters"

Comment: It would be great to provide an example input and the expected output (to this end it's better to modify your code to use a list of strings here as input rather than `sys.stdin`)

Comment: You can certainly create a list of tuples `(len(word), word)`, then sort the tuples in descending order and print the top few.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Tim if you're working with arbitrarily long input, it's better to compute the min/max as you go (ie. check for each iteration if the value is lower/higher and replace). This is more memory efficient than collecting everything, and more computing efficient than sorting all. ;)

Comment: @mozway I edited with the required outcome thanks!

Comment: @TimRoberts as Mozway explain I think "max()" "len()" are better used here.

Comment: Do you need your code to work on the standard in text stream? That seems odd, as MapReduce could be more effective processing the entire set at once instead of a line at a time (not as much opportunity for parallelisation).

Comment: @Grismar I'm not really looking for optimisation or the most efficient code here. Doing some practice runs mainly to understand the principles of mapper/reducer with a simple and visual example. Idea is to use key-pair values (Number of characters word1, Number of characters word2, to map, sort/shuffle, then reduce to obtain the max(key/characters) = (number of characters - Word1, Word2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you ask.  This keeps only the top 5 words, which makes it a lot easier to sort.  The "print" in the loop is only for debugging and can be removed.

```
import sys
top5 = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        top5.append( (len(word),word) )
        top5.sort( reverse=True )
        top5 = top5[:5]
    print(top5)
print( "Top 5 words by length are:" )
print(top5)
```